# How to get charles proxy working with an akka app?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, akka, charles-proxy

I am not sure how to get charles proxy working when running an akka app using sbt.

At the moment my outgoing connections are not being reporting in charles.

My akka app is making an outgoing http connection to download data and I want to monitor the http headers etc.

I read I have to make these changes:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8888");
```

https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/configuration/browser-and-system-configuration/

Answer (score 0):

The Akka HTTP client does not currently support http proxying (https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/16853). Not sure if there are any other options to snoop on a HTTP client using Charles (something like how WireShark works), but if there is that would be the way to go right now.